# UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront only works every other time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app I'm attempting to use the front camera by default in a `UIImagePicker`. I know, seems simple enough...

```
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

Now, the first time I launch my picker everything works fine and the front camera is initialized, but when the picker is dismissed, and presented again the back camera is used. From there on out if I continuously open and close the picker the camera used will be: front, back, front, back, front, back...

I've stripped this code down to the bare basics of the picker attempting to isolate the problem and it persists. Has anyone run into this issue before? Any pointers or direction would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Problem solved! I was calling `imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];` in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear`!

Comment: Can you please post a snippet showing how you're initializing/presenting/dismissing the controller ? (I think I know what's wrong but it would be a long shot without any basic information)

Comment: I'm glad that you found the culprit :) I've also posted this as an answer as per your request.

Comment: Thank you! This has been bugging me as well! Can anyone explain what the init difference is between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem **must** be at how you try to initialize/present/dismiss your controller.

So, why this back and forth between cameras?

It seems that the underlying `AVCaptureSession` for some reason kept running after the dismiss of the controller. So the next time you presented it, it tried to add the input but it was bussy, so went to the next available (the rear camera), interrupted itself (thus freeing the previous one) and so on.

Comment: @SamBudda The solution is to call it inside `viewDidAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad` so to get a fresh controller and give it a chance to free the session (there is also an explanation on the comments provided from OP after solving this issue)

Comment: See my problem here it still didn't work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614428/uiimagepickercontrollercameradevicefront-works-every-other-time/14615865#14615865

Comment: Make sure that `imagePicker` is, in fact, released. I had the same problem and a `[imagePicker release]` (old, non-ARC project) solved the issue, allowing the image picker to be re-created with the correct camera next time around.